# do { } while (false) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In C++, I sometimes use the following kind of code:

```cpp
do {
  if (!cond1) break; // bail-out
  if (!cond2) break; // bail-out
  // and so on with many more conditions

  // finally:
  // do what I actually want to do
  // when none of the previous conditions caused a bail-out
} while (false);
```

Thus, the `do { } while (false);` is actually not intended as loop but simply a trick for a convenient alternative to `if`-`else` cascades. (Please, note that all happens in one block scope with all its positive implications.)

Now, I would like to do something similar in Python but I would like to learn whether there is a *Pythonic* alternative.

Comment: I'd break that out into a smaller function that you can `return` out of.

Comment: @AKX Python does support local functions (functions in functions), well? That could be an alternative, and I just would use `return` instead of `break`. That sounds not that bad.

Comment: It would just be a conventional infinite loop (`while True: ...`) with an unconditional `break` at the end.

Comment: Or you could do `for _ in range(1):`. But I think it is cleaner to make this a function and use `return`.

Comment: @chepner This is what I already considered as well but the `break` at the end of loop body made me uncertain a bit. (It somehow looks scaring...) ;-)

Comment: The other idiomatic way is `if...elif...elif...else` which is not quite what you want, but does avoid cascades of endlessly indented `else` clauses.

Comment: @Scheff, ...yes, Python does support nested functions, though they're named rather than anonymous. Same syntax as defining a function in any other context.

Comment: I've got to say, this seems like a totally janky use of `do-while` in C++. I'm sure it's an idiom but it's weird

Comment: `if ... elif ... ` isn't really a great solution (the `elif` clauses would all just contain `pass`). Basically, it's a work around for the fact that you can't break/return from an arbitrary block, just a loop. So you create a loop that can only run once regardless.

Comment: I think it's more common in C/C++ to just use `goto` (no, not every use of `goto` is an abomination): `{ if ! cond1: goto END; if ! cond2: goto END; ...; END: ; }` or similar.

Comment: Perl lets you do something similar, as a block is the same as a one-time loop: `{ last if cond1; last if cond2; ... }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there's nothing you want to do in between checking the conditions, then the cleanest solution is like this:

```py
if cond1 and cond2 and cond3:
    do_thing()
```

Assuming you *do* want to do some things in between checking the conditions, here are a few options, in order of subjective Pythonicity.

The cleanest solution is probably to put your code into a function and use `return` instead of `break`; note that you can write this as a local function, there is no need to expose every function declared in your code. However, if the function is useful enough then you might consider exposing it anyway.

```py
def do_thing_on_conditions():
    if not cond1: return
    if not cond2: return
    if not cond3: return
    do_thing()
do_thing_on_conditions()
```

The `do`/`while(false)` idiom is essentially a loop structure which iterates once and only once, so you can write it as a `for` loop over a sequence of length 1:

```py
for _ in range(1):
    if not cond1: break
    if not cond2: break
    if not cond3: break
    do_thing()
```

Finally, you could do this: but I don't recommend it, because (like the `do`/`while(false)` idiom) you have to read all the way to the end to know this will only iterate once.

```
while True:
    if not cond1: break
    if not cond2: break
    if not cond3: break
    do_thing()
    break
```

Comment: I tried the `if`-`elif` but it doesn't work out well. Between the conditions, I need statements which build up for the further conditions. This would fit quite nice in each of your last 3 snippets. I will give them a try. And, thanks for enlightening me.